# Is the car/wall comparison valid for speeds close to $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, velocity

At school, people commonly think about momentum and conservation of energy using the example of a car collision. A common phrase is "Do not try to think of two objects moving, think of one moving at the sum of both speeds and the other stopped. After all you are in one of the cars, and from your point of view, your are still and the wall is coming really fast!".

Does that principle apply to near light speeds? Will I see the other guy "growing" in my field of view and by projection, calculate his speed at $2c$ or will time dilatation work some kind of really cool phenomenon there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the relative speed of two near-light speed particles headed towards each other?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113818/)

Comment: Hi Leonardo. I've suggested what seems the most obvious duplicate explaining how to calculate relative velocities at relativitic speeds, but really any of the [questions about the relativistic addition of velocities](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=relativistic+addition+velocity) would address your question.

Comment: Even if the question is a duplicate, I'd like to give you props for not coming to the conclusion that Einstein was wrong after five minutes of thinking.

Comment: That viewpoint that the people at your school are using can be highly misleading; it famously caused a Mythbuster to think that two cars hitting each other head-on both at speed $v$ would result in more carnage than a car hitting a wall at speed $v$ (actual result: equal carnage due to symmetry). The problem is that it's really easy to forget to account for the kinetic energy $\frac 12 (2m) v^2$ carried off by the center of mass after the collision occurs, so it's tempting to think that this energy goes into the wreck when it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The Earth as a rest frame is arbitrary. So saying that two cars have velocities toward each other is just a choice of reference frame. You are right that you can consider yourself to be at rest while the car coming toward you has some speed which is twice what the Earth frame would say it has.

As it comes toward you, you observe it to have a contracted length. Also, the Earth which seems to be coming at you will have a contracted length. The closer the other car gets to the speed of light in your frame, the shorter it becomes as it heads toward you. This will also happen to the Earth. You may be surprised at how quickly a near light speed Earth travels beneath your car. It not only passes by quickly because of its speed but also because it seems contracted to you, in fact the entire solar system will seem contracted.

This is one of the lesser known aspects of special relativity. If you travel to a nearby star at close to the speed of light, then you experience less time on the trip there. But how can this be? On the ship you feel like time is passing normally. And it is for you, but the universe ahead of you is contracted to be shorter. So you can travel to distant locations in a very short period of time from our point of view. In fact, at near light speed, the distant stars can be less than a light year away. At tremendously close to light speed the entire universe becomes accessible within a few years of time on the ship.