# Particles approach each other with .8c

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

Two particles travelling with velocity .8c (observed from ground frame) each approach each other.
What is their relative velocity wrt ground frame.
According to me they should be added.
I am very much aware that their relative velocity wrt each other is smaller than c i.e is velocity of one particle wrt other.

[What is the relative speed of two near-light speed particles headed towards each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113818/)

Comment: FWIW, their relative speed is 40c/41.

Comment: What's with the off-topic close votes? This seems to me to be a question stemming from legitimate confusion about what it means to add velocities in special relativity.

Comment: This is unclear. Is the $0.8 c$ their speed relative to the ground or relative to each other? You ask for “relative velocity wrt ground”, which is not what “relative velocity” usually means.

Comment: @G.Smith 0.8c is their velocity as observed from ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you: just add the velocities (or rather, subtract them: one has velocity $0.8c$, and the other $-0.8c$).  In the ground frame, the distance between the particles decreases at a rate of $1.6c$.  This does not violate any laws of physics.